# Why do all of the monitors have owned seem to get dead pixels a short time after using them?

Tags: display, external-display

I recently got a new monitor from a different manufacturer some time after my old one had gotten a dead pixel. However not even a month after purchasing it the new one had developed a dead pixel. The same thing happened to my Oculus Rift S after receiving a replacement after getting a defective headset.

I’m starting to wonder if this isn't a coincidence. Could there be something causing this to happen or is this some ungodly series of unfortunate events?

Comment: Never had that problem but I only buy Dell first tier monitors

Answer (score 2):

First, be sure they're really dead pixels (some malware may leave a one-pixel image onscreen). Use a tool such as free [IsMyLcdOk](https://www.softwareok.com/?Download=IsMyLcdOK) to check the screen. Tthe <kbd>F6</kbd> command on that tool can cycle all pixels through all states, possibly fixing a stuck pixel (**If you are bothered by rapid flickering, use with caution**).

You might perform a full malware scan using an *alternate* tool from your current suite.

However, it *is possible* to damage LCD displays.

- LCD devices are [sensitive to heat and mechanical pressure or shock](https://dmohankumar.wordpress.com/2012/08/29/why-lcd-screen-damage-easily-tech-focus-7/).
- LCD devices can be [damaged by electrostatic discharge](https://riverdi.com/how-to-protect-the-display-from-esd-damage/).

Normally, these are fairly rugged devices, but left in a hot automobile, the liquid crystals can permanently lose they're alignment. In a dry climate, static picked up from walking across carpeting can accumulate 10,000 V or more, and touching the screen could *possibly* cause damage.

**N.B.** Manufacturers [*expect* a certain number of dead pixels](https://www.tested.com/tech/1337-we-uncover-the-dead-pixel-policies-for-every-major-lcd-maker/). For example, Apple considers up to 15 dead cells "acceptable" on a 22" - 30" monitor, Acer allows up to 16 defects on a 2048x1536 display. Usually, out of 2,073,600 pixels on a 1080p display, a few stuck pixels are unnoticeable, unless working on high-reslution still images.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Its clearly a dead pixel. I've tried software like this before and Have had no look on getting it to fade. The carpet and heat could potentially be the cause of the issue since my room is carpeted, and I have a desk that im unable to move that's in front of my window, though the curtains are usually shut. I live in Texas so dry hot summers are common. I wish It was possible to move my desk, but theres no space in my room.